# expo do we need two google map api key?

Tags: react-native, expo

from the expo guide to use google map in stand alone app, we need to restrict the key to `android apps`

[image]

So can we still use the same map api key for ios app ? or do we need to create map api key to use specifically for ios ?

Answer (score 0):

Both are available through the `API key` received through the **Google Console**. If it is a stand-alone app, both `iOS` and `Android` must be set up.

**Get the API key**

You must have at least one API key associated with your project.

To get an API key:

1. Go to the Google Cloud Platform Console.
2. From the Project drop-down menu, select or create the project for
   which you want to add an API key.
3. From the  Navigation menu, select APIs & Services > Credentials.
4. On the Credentials page, click Create credentials > API key.
   The API key created dialog displays your newly created API key (an
   encrypted string).
5. Click Close.  The new API key is listed on the Credentials page
   under API keys.  (Remember to restrict the API key before using it
   in production.)

**Specify your Google Maps API Key on Android:**

Add your API key to your manifest file (`android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`):

```java
<application>
   <!-- You will only need to add this meta-data tag, but make sure it's a child of application -->
   <meta-data
     android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
     android:value="Your Google maps API Key Here"/>
</application>
```

**Enabling Google Maps on iOS**

If you want to enable **Google Maps on iOS**, obtain the Google API key and edit your `AppDelegate.m` as follows:

```
+ #import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>

@implementation AppDelegate
...
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
+  [GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"_YOUR_API_KEY_"]; // add this line using the api key obtained from Google Console
...
```

Comment: do we need to create two map api keys?

Comment: @angrykiwi You can create one key in the Google Console and enter the same key each.

Comment: ah ok. Now back to my original question. I was asking about expo. they restrict api key to android only. that means we can not use in ios. cant have one key. Is that right?

Comment: @angrykiwi It means that iOS works without configuration. To save your google map api key, just save it as my answer. `[GMSServices provideApiKey:@"your api key"]`

Comment: And now my answer is when it is a stand-alone app, as you asked.